# Crystal Reports Location Character equals full name

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Our current location table uses only the first letter of each city. I would like to display the full name of the city on the report when filtering by location.

For example:

```
{oeordhdr_sql.mfg_loc}
Location F = Fresno
```

I would like to display Fresno on the report where the filter location is being implemented.

My custom Function
Function (Stringvar value)
  if (Strcmp(trim(value), "F") = 0) then
    "Fresno"
  if (Strcmp(trim(value), "D") = 0) then
    "Denver" 
  if (Strcmp(trim(value), "K") = 0) then
    "Knoxville" 
  if (Strcmp(trim(value), "L") = 0) then
    "Lakeland" 
  else
    value

Gives me error stating the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula,

Answer (score 0):

Naive, but you could define a function to map the values for you. Assuming there are no more than 26 cities, you could write this by hand. Otherwise you could write a small program in some other language to generate it for you.

**To create a new formula:**

> 1. In the top toolbar, *Report* -> *Formula Workshop*
> 2. Right click on *Report Custom Functions* -> *New*
> 3. Name your function, use editor

And now write your function:

```
Function (Stringvar value)
  if (Strcmp(trim(value), "F") = 0) then
    "Fresno" 
  if (Strcmp(trim(value), 'G") = 0) then
    "Greensboro"
  else
    value
```

Now you can create a new Formula Field,  and define it as such:

```
MyFunction( {YOUR_TABLE_OR_SP} )
```

And add it to your report.

Comment: Hi yes my experience in crystal is weak and growing, LOL. IM not following where to enter the function (stringvar) part?

Comment: @Felson I've edited my answer to demonstrate creating a new formula.

Comment: I get an error on the custom function the ) is Missing, with the first then highlighted.

Comment: And if I save anyways, im not seeing the custom function in the function drop down

Comment: @Felson just like any coding language, you need to balance the open and close parens. Edited. As for not seeing the custom function, I'm not sure what drop down you are referring to.

Comment: in the formula workshop, when I create the formula field, in the function column I do not see my custom function I created.

Comment: For most part yes, but crystal knowledge is where im not experienced.

Comment: added ) after 0 but still get error that the remaining is not part of formula.